# history is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BrowserRouter>,ts 2322

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../index.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
  BrowserRouter,
  BrowserRouterProps
} from "react-router-dom";
import history from "../../history";
import Modal from "../Modal";

interface CustomInputProps extends BrowserRouterProps {
  history?: any;
}

class App extends Component<CustomInputProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Router history={history}> //Здесь подчеркивает Router
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/' component={Modal}/>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;


//history.tsx
// import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
// export default createHistory();
```

Answer (score 0):

я удалил оберту BrowserRouter и изменил импорты на import { Route, Router, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom"; и это сработало